# How can I generate multipages pdf from php script

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation

How can I generate multipage PDF files from php loop, with a fixed header and footer in each page, and a table with multiple columns in the body of each pdf file ?

I have tried with zend_pdf, but I give up because I can't easily clone my header and footer in each page... an I get other problems with the tables...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

DOM PDF is the php module I've used for this before. Maybe you will get better results from that.

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/